# Replacing strings from multiple array elements delimited by commas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, array, replace

In QGIS 3.18, I have a vector layer of 1000+ features with 100+ attributes, many of which are strings of concatenated elements (substrings) delimited by commas. Some of those elements need to be replaced by other elements - entire elements as delimited, not parts of elements.

What I have done in the past to get the job done is to use `replace()` expressions with 20+ clauses in them. Besides being long and unwieldy, this method was extremely impractical due to the fact that some of the elements are contained as substrings within other elements: for example, one element might be `'51.1'`, another might be `'51.11'` or `'51.111'`, but these need to be treated and replaced differently. With the `replace` method, this got very messy very fast and required a lot of cleanup work.

I am looking to do this with an `array` function, which recognizes delimited elements. I have tried several attempts, such as: `array_to_string(regexp_replace(string_to_array("Field_A",','),'51.1','String1'))` which the Field Calculator recognizes as a valid expression but which returns no results, and

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        string_to_array("Field_A",','),
        regexp_replace(@element,'51.1','String1')
    )
)
```

which returns results but seems not to be identifying the delimited elements, as I have the same problem as with `replace`. Example: `51.11` is replaced as `String11`.

I need to be able to list many substring replacements in one expression, if possible.

As an example of the sort of thing I want to do, see the last line of the table below:

[image: example]

Note: I cannot use `array_replace` as I am unable to upgrade to QGIS 3.20 on this device at the moment, and this function is unavailable on 3.18.

Comment: Can you please either show us your data or share it?

Comment: Just change `'51.1'` to `'^51.1$'` in your second expression, perhaps?

Comment: Hi @Taras, I'm not exactly sure the best way to show/share my data in a way that would be useful, so I've uploaded a table of sample data (not my real data but shows what I want to do). I hope it's clear; let me know if something else would be more helpful.

Comment: @Kazuhito, this does indeed work for me for one element at a time. If I try to put in additional `regexp_replace` terms, I can't get the expression to work.  (I have a lot of terms to replace, so I need them all in one expression if possible.)

Comment: Sorry, not clear for mea what you want to replace: input is the last line of `Existing data` in your screenshot? And how should the output look like?

Comment: @Babel I want to replace each element in an array (such as 51.1) with another element corresponding to it (such as String1). In the example above, the last line of `Existing data` is a sample array, and column `Desired result` is what I want the output to look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this combining arrays with maps (`key:value` pairs, see [help Maps Functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#maps-functions)) and the following expression, where in line 4 you list the elements you want to replace, using the pattern `'value_old','value_new'`.

Explanation: The expression creates an array of all inputs in `fieldA` (line 6) and for each element (line 5) looks in the map (the one from line 4, created as a variable `@map`: line 2/3) at what position a key with this values from the array occurs in the map and returns the corresponding value (function [map_get](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#map-get), line 7):

```
array_to_string (
    with_variable(
        'map',
        map('51.1','String1','51.11','String2','51.111','String3','51.13','String4','51.15','String5'),
        array_foreach (
            string_to_array (fieldA),
            map_get (@map,@element)
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: A bunch of great and helpful answers on this thread -- thanks to all. I accepted this one because of its simplicity and because it fit really well with my existing workflow.

Comment: Brilliant! Excellent use case of `map()` and `map_get()`!!!

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito - I feel honored by your comment. Indeed, combining maps and arrays offers a lot of (still underused, I have the impression) possibilities.

Comment: Very elegant indeed. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex expression to find the text to be replaced. It should be `'(^|,)15.1(,|$)'`

The first `(^|,)` is a capture group, which means to find either the beginning of the string (`^`) or a `,`. Then there is your text of interest and at last another capture group `(,|$)` which finds either a `,` or the end of the string (`$`)

With this expression, it will find `15.1`, `0,15.1`, `15.1,0`, `0,15.1,0` but NOT `15.11`

When replacing the found string, you must include the two search groups in the replaced text, using `\\1` and `\\2`

For a single text to be replaced, the expression becomes:

```
regexp_replace(myColumn,'(^|,)15.1(,|$)','\\1string1\\2'),'(^|,)
```

To have multiple replacements, you can either nest calls to `regexp_replace`, such as

```
regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
        myColumn, '(^|,)15.1(,|$)', '\\1string1\\2'
        ), '(^|,)15.2(,|$)', '\\1string2\\2'
    )
```

Or, if you have many, you can create a function that makes X replacement one after another. It would be cleaner and easier to maintain, as in @fastest answer.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to me a good task to be solved with Python and Function Editor. I have tried to build a minimum code fragment that uses the data provided in your example:

1. Start from a memory layer that has 2 attributes `"StringSource"` and `"StringDest"` and six features that have the `"StringSource"` attribute set as in your example:

   [image]

2.Using the function editor, I define the function `str_convert()` as follows:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

def map_str(str_in=None):
    lst_str_map = ["51.1", "51.11", "51.111", "51.13", "51.15"]
    if str_in not in lst_str_map:
        raise ValueError("Invalid source for string.")
    return f"String{lst_str_map.index(str_in):02d}"
 
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesgeometry=False)
def str_convert(feature, parent):
    lst_in = [el for el in feature["StringSource"].split(",") if el]
    str_out = ",".join([map_str(el) for el in lst_in])
    return str_out
```

3. The function shows up under the "Custom" menu and the expression editor shows the result of the function evaluated for a given feature.

   [image]
4. Finally, using the field calculator, apply the `str_convert()` function to compute the content of the `"StringDest"` attribute for each feature.

   [image]
5. After clicking <kbd>Ok</kbd>, the `"StringDest"` attribute of the feature is correctly filled.

   [image]

The nice thing is that the code to convert the strings is fully encapsulated into the `map_str()` function and it can be changed rather easily.

Answer (score 4):

You can use PyQGIS (I don't have all numbers in my sample data, so the numbering isn't correct):

```py
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('New scratch layer')[0]

sourcefield = 'data1'
targetfield = 'data2'

allvals = [f[sourcefield] for f in lyr.getFeatures()] #List all values
allvals = [f.split(',') for f in allvals] #Split them into individual elements
allvals = list(set([item for sublist in allvals for item in sublist])) #Unpack all sublist and remove duplicate elements
allvals.sort(key=lambda x: float(x)) #Sort
replacedict = {x:'String{}'.format(e) for e, x in enumerate(allvals, 1)} #Create a dictionary with element number as key, and enumerate number as value

#Update the field
ix = lyr.fields().indexFromName(targetfield)
attrmap = {}
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    newval = ','.join([replacedict[x] for x in f[sourcefield].split(',')])
    attrmap[f.id()] = {ix: newval}
lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrmap)
```

[image]